# Regex capture repeating groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have an input that looks like this:

```
<ID>0<VAL>a1b<ID>1<VAL>a2b<ID>2<VAL>a3b<ID>3<VAL>a4b
```

I'd need to capture key-value pairs (e.g. `id - val`) or at least an array of groups as the following:
`[0, a1b, 1, a2b, 2, a3b, 3, a4b]`

Capturing just one pair (i.e. when the input contains only a single pair) works with this:

```
(?>(?:<ID>(\d+))(?:<VAL>(.+)))?
```

the result being: `[0, a1b]`.

But it doesn't work for multiple pairs - it captures 0 as a group then as a 2nd group it takes the rest of the input, excluding the first `<VAL>` tag, as in: `[0, a1b<ID>1<VAL>a2b<ID>2<VAL>a3b<ID>3<VAL>a4b]`

Can someone point me to a direction I should look into?

UPDATE: what if `<ID>` and `<VAL>` are some special chars, for example `0x8F` and `0x9F`?

Comment: Use multiple matching with `<ID>(\d+)<VAL>([^<]+)` - https://regex101.com/r/6jWv6t/1

Comment: If you test [your pattern on e.g. regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LMCuPG/1) you'll see that the [*greedy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) `.+` consumes all the rest from the first value match. Maybe you can use `\w` word-character for the `VAL`. With the optional group you could use [`<ID>(\d+)(?:<VAL>(\w+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/owgong/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex matches keys and then values.

`(?<=<ID>)(\d+)(?=<VAL>)|(?<=<VAL>)[a-z\d]*(?=<ID>)`

There are 2 groups:

- `(?<=<ID>)(\d+)(?=<VAL>)` matches a key `\d+` between `<ID>` and `<VAL>` using positive lookbehind and lookahead

  - `(?<=<ID>)` is a positive lookbehind
  - `(?=<VAL>)` is a positive lookahead
- `(?<=<VAL>)[a-z\d]*(?=<ID>)` matches a value between `<VAL>` and `<ID>` using positive lookbehind and lookahead

  - `[a-z\d]*` matches a value
  - `(?<=<VAL>)` is a positive lookbehind
  - `(?=<ID>)` is a positive lookahead

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JhwuPf/1)

Comment: thank you for your answer, the current regex doesn't capture the <VAL> values, also it doesn't capture the last <VAL> value. A solution to that would be:

`(?<=<ID>)(\d+)(?=<VAL>)|(?<=<VAL>)([a-z\d]*)(?=<ID>)?`

- added `?` for the last group
- created a capture group for values [a-z\d]*

Comment: For hex delimiters, the regex would look similar to 
`(?<=\x8A)(\d+)(?=\x9A)|(?<=\x9A)([a-z\d]*)(?=\x8A?)`.
Also, as it is now, it is quite restrictive, so in case there is need to capture more complex values (e.g. values that include '.' or ':'), just update the value capture: `([a-zA-Z\d\.\:\s]*)`

Answer (score 1):

@bobble-bubble's solutions is the most efficient (according to regex101): 4 matches in 72 steps and 1ms, but it's very restrictive. To fix this, the `\w` can be replaced with `[a-z\d]`, then it becomes even faster: 4 matches in 72 steps and 0ms.

@WiktorStribiżew's solution is the next most efficient: 4 matches in 64 steps and 4ms.

@albina's solution is the least efficient: 7 matches in 153 steps and 10ms